# How to add slide up animation for an image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am building a Wordpress Theme and am using Envira to have a responsive Gallery. I want to add some CSS and javascript/jquery to add an animation to my three pictures in that gallery. I want them to appear and slide up from the bottom when scrolling to the section of that page. Here's an example of what I am looking for:

https://www.beau-rivage.ch

Basically, when you scroll down, you see those three pictures/slides coming up. I tried to google this but couldn't find any code that worked for me. So currently I do not have any code to share for this animation and the Envira Gallery pictures are just added via a shortcode. Can anyone help me and point me in the right direction?

Would much appreciate your support!

Comment: I suggest this : https://michalsnik.github.io/aos/

Comment: go through https://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **animate.css** (https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) and **wow.js** combination if you don't want to write code manually.
Check **https://wowjs.uk/** examples.